# Plotting spectrogram but returned weird results

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing

I already have some audio converted to spectrogram image using `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` function.

After some operations on the image, now I would like to save it as an image file.

My simple thought was that since the data are already numpy arrays, I could just plot them.

The code was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import imageio

im = imageio.imread(path/0.png')
plt.plot(im)
plt.show()
```

However, it returns very weird image as shown.

[image]

1. The image looks weird and obviously is not recognized as spectrograms
2. The original image was greyscale with shape `(256, 128)`, how come the returned image has different colors?
3. What should I do now? Is it the wrong parameters setting that caused the results?

Comment: You plot each column of your image as a line. That is what `plot` is supposed to do. You probably want to use `imshow` to show the image. Or maybe `imsave` to save it? Not sure what the desired outcome is though?

Answer (score 0):

similar to the demonstration in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html, you should be using the plt.pcolormesh function instead of the plt.plot. Currently, you are plotting each of the spectrogram's lines separately.